# Update of nested document with update function with $set results in "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query."

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am trying to change the price of `middle` in a second element of the document from 15.00 to 17.00:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60042d16540eae75f0acd6bd"),
    "name" : "Bolonian",
    "ingredients" : [ 
        "ham", 
        "salami", 
        "becon", 
        "chili", 
        "cheese"
    ],
    "prices" : [ 
        {
            "small" : 15.0
        }, 
        {
            "middle" : 21.0
        }, 
        {
            "big" : 30.0
        }
    ]
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60042d16540eae75f0acd6be"),
    "name" : "Margherita",
    "ingredients" : [ 
        "tomato souce", 
        "cheese"
    ],
    "prices" : [ 
        {
            "small" : 11.0
        }, 
        {
            "medium" : 15.0
        }, 
        {
            "big" : 24.0
        }
    ]
}
```

With function:

```
function change_price(name_of_pizza, size, new_price){
    db.pizza.update({ "name" : name_of_pizza}, {$set: { ["prices.$." + size] : new_price}});
}
    
change_price("Margherita", "middle", 17.00)
```

However, I receive an error: 
`The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.`

How can I set the nested value of middle price from 15 to 17 in a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), The filtered positional operator `$[<identifier>]` identifies the array elements that match the `arrayFilters` conditions for an update operation.

- try `$exists` operator to check is field available

```
db.pizza.update(
  { "name": name_of_pizza },
  { $set: { ["prices.$[p]." + size]: new_price } },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { ["p." + size]: { $exists: true } }
    ]
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MdurJpFDDaf)